Queues wait for other queues: A communication problem
I am working on a problem which involves a single server that requires multiple inputs to do a computation. Each of these inputs arrive as a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Hence, a situation arises where a particular input from one queue has to wait for all other corresponding inputs from other queues to arrive.
I need to calculate the channel capacity of such a system. Assume N inputs to the server (N parallel queues) and the service time of the server is $ Exp(\mu)$.
If it were only one input (trivial case with no waiting for other queues), I could use the Pollaczek-Khinchin formula for queue and the fact that the capacity is $\lambda$ times the Laplace transform of waiting time distribution to find the capacity (as described in arXiv:1804.00906v3)
However, in this case the service time becomes layer dependent since there is an additional wait of $Max_N (\Gamma(j,\lambda)) - \Gamma(j,\lambda)$ for a bit in the $j^{th}$ "layer" or the queue due to the waiting policy described above. Hence the total service time distribution becomes $Max_N (\Gamma(j,\lambda)) - \Gamma(j,\lambda) +  Exp(\mu) $ which is dependent on the position in the queue and very hard to calculate. I am not sure how to proceed in this case and any help would be much appreciated.
Cross posted from: https://mathoverflow.net/q/468902/526203 because I did not know which community this question would fit better into.
